OSRMRoadManager causes crashes occasionally
In my application I use an osm map and I add a route to the map with the help of osmdroidbonus pack. I try this with the help of
I use OSRMRoadManager to get route in the following function:
In my application I use an osm map and I add a route to the map with the help of osmdroidbonus pack. The problem arises when the  roadManager is initialized as it occasionally results in crash. I thought that the problem might be the null result of OSRMRoadManager, but it seems that it is not.
I use OSRMRoadManager to get route in the following function:
 private void routing(double lat, double lng) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG,"ROUTE STARTED");
                        try {
                            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(getApplicationContext(), "coffeeshopper");
                            if (roadManager == null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "null");
                            } else {

                                ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                                waypoints.add(userLoc);
                                waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(lat, lng));
                                ((OSRMRoadManager) roadManager).setMean(OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_FOOT);

                                Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

                                Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
                                map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){

                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }.start();```

It works usually, but occasionally I get crash. How can I avoid this issue?

I also added this to the onCreate         
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
But it did not really help

According to Logs it is the
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(getApplicationContext(), "coffeeshopper");
That causes the crash
Do you happen to know how to solve this issue?
 private void routing(double lat, double lng) {
        new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        Log.d(TAG,"ROUTE STARTED");
                        try {
                            RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(getApplicationContext(), "coffeeshopper");
                            if (roadManager == null) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "null");
                            } else {

                                ArrayList<GeoPoint> waypoints = new ArrayList<GeoPoint>();
                                waypoints.add(userLoc);
                                waypoints.add(new GeoPoint(lat, lng));
                                ((OSRMRoadManager) roadManager).setMean(OSRMRoadManager.MEAN_BY_FOOT);

                                Road road = roadManager.getRoad(waypoints);

                                Polyline roadOverlay = RoadManager.buildRoadOverlay(road);
                                map.getOverlays().add(roadOverlay);
                            }
                        }
                        catch(Exception e){
...


    }.start();

It works usually, but occasionally I get crash. How can I avoid this issue?
I also added this to the onCreate
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
But it did not really help
According to Logs it is the
RoadManager roadManager = new OSRMRoadManager(getApplicationContext(), "coffeeshopper");
That causes the crash
Do you happen to know how to solve this issue?
